# How can I differentiate between the use of "much" as an adverb and a pronoun?

Tags: adverbs, pronouns, parts-of-speech

How to differentiate between the use of *much* as an adverb and a pronoun when it is used after a verb? Are there any easy tricks?

- It costs much. (Much=pronoun)
- Has he changed much. (much=adverb)

Comment: _Much_ is not commonly used in positive statements. _Does it cost much?_ and _It doesn't cost much_ are fine, but _It costs much_ is not. Much more usual is _It costs a lot._

Comment: Except when it is qualified - "He loves her very much." Looking at the various definitions online, I don't find dictionaries very clear or consistent in making the distinctions.

Comment: It's OK in "He asks if it costs much."